# How to get the user from a manytomanyfield in Django using Django singals and creating another object with the recived manytomany user field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-signals

I want to know is there any way where we can get the updated many to many field in one model using signals and post them to another model

```
class Post(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=24)
    nc=models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        # return self.name
m2m_changed.connect(receiver=like_post,sender=Post.nc.through)
```

I want to collect the updated record in the nc field of post model  and using signals I want to create an object using function
here is the signal that connects to Post model

```
def like_post(sender, *args, **kwargs):
    # if kwargs['action'] in ('post_update'):
    if kwargs['action'] in ('post_add', 'post_remove','post_update'):

        print(kwargs['instance'])
        instance = kwargs['instance']
        print(instance)
        notify = Notify.objects.create(
                 recipient=instance,
                 creator=Post.objects.get(pk=50),
                  state='unread',
                   type=kwargs['action'],
                )
    else:
        print('no instance')
```

in the recipient and the creator section I want to update those fields  with an existing user object the creator is the person who updated the manytomanyfield and the recipient is the person who created that post

```
notify model:
class Notify(models.Model):
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='notify_recipient',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='notify_sender',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = ('read', 'unread', 'unseen')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

whenever I run this the instance just prints the post object name and fires this error

```
ValueError at /admin/posts/post/50/change/
Cannot assign "<Post: ok>": "Notify.recipient" must be a "User" instance.
```

Comment: Well like the error says, recipient is a foreign key to User. Why are you assigning a Post there?

Comment: no the question isnt about  the error ,i want to know how to send the Foriegn key user(in the place of recipient)  to that object from manytomanyfield in post model through signals

Answer (score 1):

You can see that your **Notify** class defines `receipent` as a ForeignKey element to the **AUTH_USER_MODEL**, but you are creating a **Notify** in your signal as:

```
notify = Notify.objects.create(
                 recipient=instance,
                 creator=Post.objects.get(pk=50),
                  state='unread',
                   type=kwargs['action'],
                )
```

Here, the **instance** is an instance of `Post` rather than `User`, also **you are using `post` instance in the creator field too**. This is what causes the error.

To solve this error, you need to pass the user instance in those fields. For example, you can use something like:

```
notify = Notify.objects.create(
                     recipient=instance.nc, # find out how to pass the user of the post here
                     creator=Post.objects.get(pk=50), # replace by an user instance here instead of a post instance 
                      state='unread',
                       type=kwargs['action'],
                    )
```

**EDIT:**
To make sure that the user instance is saved you need to override the `save_model` method of your ModelAdmin for post model as:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    if not form.cleaned_data['nc']:
        form.cleaned_data['nc'] = [request.user]
    form.save_m2m()
```

Comment: Cannot assign "<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x06E5E150>": "Notify.recipient" must be a "User" instance ,i got this error now

Comment: and when i print instance.nc  the terminal shows up  as auth.User.None

Comment: It is because even tough the post instance is saved, its user instance is not being saved instantly. So, first you need to make sure that data for nc is saved before the signal is executed. This error is seen in most cases where many-to-many field is used.

Comment: i understood it partially but i don't understand one thing the signal gets triggered only if the nc of that post model has been changed right? so in that case why it isnt showing the updated User and can you just elaborate the  possible ways to solve this issue

Comment: I don't quiet understand your query about using **m2m_changed** signal here. You stated it correct that the signal gets triggered only if the nc of that post model has been changed. So, thinking of activating the signal with change of any other fields rather than nc is of no use.

Comment: the reason why i use m2m_changed is to check the followers feature to that particular post, the user may follow that post or unfollow it. so the user who created that post will come to know that the so and so users are following your post

Comment: but i cant understand how to add that User foriegnkey thing to the notify model using signals

Comment: check my edited answer where I have mentioned how to add the user instance in the post object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195792/discussion-between-mounikes-mintu-and-sanip).